# Apache POI pptx - error saving basic presentation

Tags: java, apache-poi

I boiled opening and saving a presentation with Apache POI down to the most basic thing I can think of:

```
XMLSlideShow output = new XMLSlideShow(new FileInputStream("test.pptx"));
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("test out.pptx");
output.write(out);
out.close();
output.close();
```

`test.pptx` is an empty presentation. I get the following error when I open `test out.pptx`:

[image: Error message]

Pressing repair works, but I don't want users to do this every time. I can open `test.pptx` without any issues. There are no errors in the console.

I use Apache POI 3.15 and eclipse Luna on windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried with another file? I've just tested your code and it worked on my side with the exact same version of POI

Comment: I open a new presentation, insert an empty title slide (or leave it empty) and I get the same result ... Very strange that you get something different. Any idea what could be the issue with my set-up?